# Appstore Auto Renewable Subscription for country specific

Tags: app-store, in-app-subscription, auto-renewable

Can we create auto renewable subscription tied with country/territory? I have to create certain subscriptions for specific countries. Show/hide some **subscription as per country**.

ex.

- Subscription 1 for India, Bangladesh
- Subscription 2 for India, US, Canada
- Subscription 3 for India

How do we manage visibility of subscription as per country/territory?

Answer (score 0):

We need to store and map all products created on Appstore IAP on our server and map product with country availability.

Appstore storefront has its country/region, using same we can manage visibility of the products on UI.